# Onclick dynamically added setAttribute to td element passes variable as string

Tags: javascript, onclick, setattribute

I have a dynamically created table with one cell containing a button.  I used setAttribute to insert the onclick event but the variable that it is using is passed as a string and not a variable. The two point function just adds points to the player that is passed in.  It works in a static table, just not when I use the setAttribute method

```js
eletble.setAttribute('onclick', 'TwoPoints(student1);');
```

Comment: student1 is just a variable that changes based on which student has scored.  Once the table is populated there could be say 10 students.  So this needs to pass the correct student name to the TwoPoints function.  I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table, use a cell or row per student and delegate from the tbody

```js
const TwoPoints = student => console.log(student,"Two points");

document.getElementById("eletble").addEventListener("click", function(e) { 
  const tgt = e.target;
  TwoPoints(tgt.dataset.student) 
});
```

```html
<table>
<tbody id="eletble">
<tr><td data-student="Student 1">Student number 1</td></tr>
<tr><td data-student="Student 2">Student number 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```